# Selenium c#: Unable to click button

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having problems running the following code to click a button.

When I run as debug and step through, I can find the button and click it without any problems. But during an actual run it is unable to click the button.

Any suggestions please?

```
 new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Name("searchType"))).SelectByText("Location");
 new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("Location"))).SelectByText("Brentwood");
 Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
 var button = Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn-go"));
 button.Click();
```

Comment: Why do you click the button programmatically? Can't you just move the code from button event handler to a method and call it instead?

Comment: @Alex question is about automation using selenium.

Comment: @Alex. I have tried putting the button into a separate method but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your time from 5 to approx 40 in below code:-

```
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
```

you can use WebDriverWait also for that element. Refer below link for same:-

http://watirmelon.com/2014/01/29/waiting-in-c-webdriver/

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private WebDriverWait wait;
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Name("searchType"))).SelectByText("Location");
new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("Location"))).SelectByText("Brentwood");


wait.Until(driver1 => (driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn-go"))));
Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn-go")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Explicit Wait. In this example, it will wait up to 60 seconds before throwing a `Timeout Exception`. But if element found before 60 seconds, it will return the same.

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

        new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("searchType"))).SelectByText("Location");
        new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Location"))).SelectByText("Brentwood");


        IWebElement button = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) => { return driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn-go")); });

        button.Click();
```